# How do a database know which comment to add on which post on browser side? (PHP, MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, comments, blogs

Lets say we have two tables in our database. 
1- Comments
2-Posts
Both have one row of unique id number. EDIT: Comments table also has the post id row.
Now say we have 200 posts on a page and each has a comment box below it. How do we refrence from browser side before adding it to Comments table that this comment should go with this post's id number. (or whatever)

I can insert it from backend but my question is how do we refrence each comment box with it's post from frontend or from browser.

Comment: When you design the database you link the 2 tables with a foreign key,so maybe each comment is inserted with the post id.

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking: how to create the datastructure or do you have some specific problem in php. Show us perhaps the code and where your problem is..

Comment: @Pleun I'm asking about how can I make the comment box know that this belongs to this foregn key of this specific post FROM FRONT END. In other words how to get a specific post from front end. Let's say I have 200 posts in a page I wanna make a comment on one when I choose the post how does the php gonna know that what does I selected? So that it can put the comment in the right place in the database? I hope you understand else just tell me I'll try one more time to explain you but please help!